Restart certain services after upgrading specific packages
I'm using a few services on my Ubuntu server that are based on .NET. The .NET runtime packages are set up for automatic updates with the unattended-upgrades package. While the .NET packages (dotnet-*) can be updated just fine, the processes that use them and are still running after the update seem to get a little confused sometimes, leading to malfunctions in the service (assembly load errors or runtime files not found).
So to resolve this, I'd like to restart the affected services after those dotnet packages have been updated. The update can happen any day but only during unattended-upgrades.
I could create another service (without .NET) that watches upattended-upgrade's log file to see if any dotnet-* packages have been updated and then restart those other services. But it's a lot of annoying work.
I could also use some special option in the systemd service files of the affected services to stop them before any other service is stopped, but that probably doesn't apply to a package update, and also I've never seen systemd also restarting the stopped service later. So that probably won't help.
Is there some config option in apt or dpkg or unattended-upgrades to run a custom script with the names of the updated packages, so that I could evaluate what needs to be done after today's update? I couldn't find anything out there.

apt has a few hooks which can be used before and after it runs dpkg, and some of those are given the list of packages about to be processed. See How to get package name in apt hooks? for more information and links to references, and this answer to How can I run a script after a specific package is upgraded? for a detailed example.
Essentially, you’d write a script processing a list of packages given on its standard input, and configure it using DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkg in apt’s configuration.

Does Pre-Install-Pkg mean that my script will run before the package has actually been installed? That wouldn't help because I need the service to restart after the runtime files have been modified. Restarting it right before that won't change anything.

Have you read the linked answers? The second one in particular addresses that point.

In more detail, the problem is that Pre-Install-Pkg is the only hook that receives the list of packages. So anything relying on the list of packages has to hook that, and if it wants to actually handle it later, either schedule things for later, or store the list of packages for a later hook to process.
